# Is creating child windows expensive with winapi?

Tags: winapi

If I use a pre-defined class `emptyPanel` like this:

```
WNDCLASSW emptyPanel;

emptyPanel.style         = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
emptyPanel.lpszClassName = L"Empty Panel";
emptyPanel.hInstance     = hInstance;
emptyPanel.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_BTNFACE + 1);
emptyPanel.lpfnWndProc   = WndProc;
emptyPanel.hCursor       = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
emptyPanel.hIcon         = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);

RegisterClassW(&emptyPanel);
```

how expensive is it to call create child windows with that class like this:

```
CreateWindowW(L"Empty Panel", L"", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, 0, 0, 100, 100, hwnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

The calls to CreateWindowW are generated from within the WndProc function like this:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (msg)
    {
        ...
        case WM_USER_ADD_COMPONENT:
            callFunctionThatCreatesWindow();
            break;
        ...
    }

    return DefWindowProcW(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Where `callFunctionThatCreatesWindow` calls a different function depending on circumstance (e.g. what type of component to add), to create the window. However, in the case of this question, there is only one type of window being created.

Then to trigger the WM_USER_ADD_COMPONENT event, I call `SendMessage(hwnd, WM_USER_ADD_COMPONENT, 0, 0);` for each child window I want to create.

Creating 100+ child windows like this froze the window. Is there a better way to create child windows that have their own drawing functionality/event handlers?

Comment: no other way create window that call `[NtUser]CreateWindowExW` - of course operation is "expensive". how - but compare with what ?

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: I am using c for this

Comment: @BradenSteffaniak In the future, don't use inappropriate tags. Thank you.

Comment: @BradenSteffaniak C and C++ are separate languages with their own standards, and neither is a subset of the other. The fact that code will compile in another language, doesn't justify the tag for that language..

Comment: @BradenSteffaniak Tags should best describe the topic of the question. The code in your example being compatible with both languages is not the topic of yours.

Comment: That argument goes both ways. Tags can also be a nuisance for someone who is looking for a specific language.You could rephrase the question, in a way, such that both languages are clearly on topic. The problem there is that doing that will make the question, even broader as it currently is. Instead, I suggest your make the question as specific as possible.

Comment: This is a 100% pure winapi question. The language is irrelevant. I've re-tagged accordingly.

Comment: Creating 100 child windows shouldn't be that big a deal. If you need to do it, you need to do it. What other way is there to create these windows. I can create 200 buttons in about 100ms. I guess the answer can be found in the code you did not show. For the life of me I cannot understand why you won't produce a [mcve], This is really the most very basic debugging of a problem like this.

Answer (score 1):

> Creating 100+ child windows like this froze the window.

Doing *anything* in a loop in Windows will freeze the window. Windows is event driven and the [message pump](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644927(v=vs.85).aspx) *must be allowed to run*, or the system will 'freeze'. You should change the code to be event driven, eg. post an event (a message) and then create the child window as response to this event. Then post a second event and so on and so forth. Some may recommend to pepper the code with [message loops](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644927(v=vs.85).aspx#loop) using [`PeekMessage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644943(v=vs.85).aspx) (eg. in your 100+ loop) but I don't favor this approach.

> I call SendMessage(hwnd, WM_USER_ADD_COMPONENT, 0, 0)

Try using [`PostMessage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644944(v=vs.85).aspx) instead.

Comment: The calls to CreateWindowW are generated from within WndProc triggered by sending a user defined message WM_USER_ADD_COMPONENT with SendMessage.

Comment: Creating 100 windows shouldn't take any significant amount of time. Pumping messages whilst creating these windows could lead to all sorts of re-entrant weirdness. Better to find the real problem before you propose solutions.